# php organize divs while cycle

Tags: php, cycle

I have a `while` cycle to show the results from a query. The results are a block of content with divs, image paths, and so on.

I want organize the output by odd and even blocks. The evens goes to one "itemContainerLeft" div and the odds goes to one "itemContainerRight". I have the following code:

```
$count=0;
while($rowGroupMenu = mysql_fetch_array($rsGroupMenu)){

   echo"<div class='itemArea'>

        <h3>".$rowGroupMenu['name_teste']."</h3>";
        $menuItemID = $rowGroupMenu_2['MenuItemID'];
        $rsMenuItem = $sp->get_submenu_items($idLang, $menuItemID);

        while($rowMenuItem = mysql_fetch_array($rsMenuItem)){
        echo"<ul class='itemsSlideMenu'>
                  <li><a href='page.php?idLang=".$idLang."&menu=".$rowMenuItem['MenuItemID']."&article=".$rowMenuItem['RefArticleID']."'>".$rowMenuItem['name_teste']."</a></li>
            </ul>";} 

   echo"</div>";    
                                                            $count++;                                   
}
```

I thought this:

```
if ($count%2==0 && $count==0)
    echo("<div class='itemContainerLeft'>");         

if ($count%2==1 && $count==1)
    echo("<div class='itemContainerRight'>");
```

Just after the first `while`. But this only works for first two blocks. Any ideas how to accomplish it??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you add the `&& $count ==0` and `&& $count ==1`? That's why only first two blocks works.

```
if ($count%2==0)
    echo("<div class='itemContainerLeft'>");         

if ($count%2==1)
    echo("<div class='itemContainerRight'>");
```

Comment: You should use a `else` instead a second `if condition`

Answer (score 1):

no need to insert

```
if ($count%2==0 && $count==0) and if ($count%2==1 && $count==1)
```

use this instead of

```
if ($count%2==0)
echo("<div class='itemContainerLeft'>");
else
echo("<div class='itemContainerRight'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your && is not necessary

```
if ($count%2==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have tried
replaced `$count++;`

```
if($count==0)
    $count=1;
else 
    $count=0;
```